# python pandas: how to format big numbers in powers of ten in latex

Tags: pandas, latex

I'm using pandas to generate some large LaTex tables with big/small numbers:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(outfile),columns=['Halo','$r_{v}$','etc'])
df.to_latex("uvFlux_table_{:.1f}.tex".format(z))
```

where "outfile" is just a table of numbers (3 columns)... How can I get the numbers in outfile to be formated like:

```
$1.5x10^{12}$  &   $1.5x10^{12}$  &  $1.5x10^{-12}$
```

-- like you'd see in a scientific publication... vs the default

```
0.15e13 & 0.15e13 & 0.15e-11
```

??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining

```
def format_tex(float_number):
    exponent = np.floor(np.log10(float_number))
    mantissa = float_number/10**exponent
    mantissa_format = str(mantissa)[0:3]
    return "${0}\times10^{{{1}}}$"\
           .format(mantissa_format, str(int(exponent)))
```

you can applymap that function on a dataframe (and apply on a series)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[12345.1200000,100000000]})
df.applymap(lambda x:format_tex(x))
```

This gives already tex output in jupyter notebooks. 
Note that escaping may be tricky here. Other, faster solutions here?

Comment: That looks good... I think I just need to add a flag to capture negative numbers... and handle the log10, then I should be good.

Comment: hmm, deleted it, since the `to_latex()` didn't handle the escaping correctly.Sorry for the deletion, though. Maybe this was also due to my machine

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be a better idea not to re-invent the wheel here, and use the float formatting tools that python gives us:

```
def float_exponent_notation(float_number, precision_digits, format_type="g"):
    """
    Returns a string representation of the scientific
    notation of the given number formatted for use with
    LaTeX or Mathtext, with `precision_digits` digits of
    mantissa precision, printing a normal decimal if an
    exponent isn't necessary.
    """
    e_float = "{0:.{1:d}{2}}".format(float_number, precision_digits, format_type)
    if "e" not in e_float:
        return "${}$".format(e_float)
    mantissa, exponent = e_float.split("e")
    cleaned_exponent = exponent.strip("+")
    return "${0} \\times 10^{{{1}}}$".format(mantissa, cleaned_exponent)
```

This version is safe for zeros, negatives, etc. It rounds properly (which none of the others do!). It also gives you the option of using the `"g"` format code, which will display a number using the decimal if the decimal point would be within the precision you've set.

Also, you can pass these as formatters to the `.to_latex` method if you also pass `escape=False`. I have a formatter wrapper that does type checks and escapes if it hits a string.

Comment: I think the line with `e_float` should read `e_float = "{0:.{1:d}{2}}".format(float_number, precision_digits, format_type)`, otherwise it raises`ValueError: cannot switch from manual field specification to automatic field numbering`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Quickbeam2k1 for the answer. I've expanded to handle 0 and negative numbers:

```
# Define function for string formatting of scientific notation
def exp_tex(float_number):
    """
    Returns a string representation of the scientific
    notation of the given number formatted for use with
    LaTeX or Mathtext.
    """
    neg = False
    if float_number == 0.0:
        return r"$0.0"
    elif float_number < 0.0:
        neg = True

    exponent = np.floor(np.log10(abs(float_number)))
    mantissa = float_number/10**exponent
    if neg:
        mantissa = -mantissa
    mantissa_format = str(mantissa)[0:3]
    return "${0}\\times10^{{{1}}}$"\
           .format(mantissa_format, str(int(exponent)))
```

Comment: You're `if neg` line turns negatives into positives - not a positive development!